# Can Apple mail only sync the last month of a Exchange email?

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

I just synced my Mountain Lion Mail app with my Exchange work email account in order to have it locally on my machine (rather than continuously going through the web interface). However, now Mail fetches all the mails since the very beginning (which are a couple of years).

Is there a way (like on iOS devices) to tell Mail to only sync the last month or something configurable amount based on message count, download size or other similar restriction to prevent all messages from being stored locally?

Answer (score 1):

> The feature to prevent your Apple Mail from downloading all of your emails has been removed from the application.

[2290. How can I prevent Apple Mail from downloading all of my messages? : Frequently asked questions : ... : ITS : University of Sussex](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/help/faq?faqid=2290)

Comment: Watch out for old posts like these, finding out the answer nearly 6 years late is probably not that helpful, and the source you are citing is probably not relevant to the version of macOS they are referring to.

Answer (score -2):

Try going to Mail>MAilbox>Rebuild on each folder.  It will force a resync

Comment: Can you adjust your answer to answer the question?